# Looking for god/dess of animals

Tags: myth-identification, animals, gods

Does anyone know about a god/dess who is known to have made animals attack other gods or humans? Preferably from non-European/non-Egyptian mythologies, as I already know about the Greek examples.

Answer (score 1):

Latvian forest mother (meža māte) has some control over animals. I found a folk song:

Jāņu nakti, bāleliņi,
Nejājiet pieguļā:
Meža māte suņus sauca,
Rīdīs jūsu kumeliņus.

Which roughly translates to:

On Midsummer's night, brothers,
Do not ride to pastures:
The forest mother called the dogs,
To attack your foals.